# Displaying feedback via php when dragging a picture with dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I can't seem to display user feedback when using `dropzone.js` and PHP together, I can't see what the problem is.

I created a variable `$f` to be displayed when the form is sent with the post method but the text is not appearing when I submit via `dropzone.js`

```
<?php
require_once'FileClass.php';    
$fileHandler = new handleFiles();      

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {

    $f = "hhh";

    if ($fileHandler->is_file_allowed($_FILES['file']['name'], $_FILES['file']['size'], $_FILES['file']['type'])) {
        $feedback = "Image submitted your link: " . "YOUR_LINK" . " " . $fileHandler->generateURL($_FILES['file']['name'],$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_POST["tags"]);
}
    else {
        $feedback = "Something went wrong try again make sure your image is in jpg, jpeg, or png form";
    }
}
    else {
        $feedback = "Something went wrong try again make sure your image is in jpg, jpeg, or png form";
    }        
}    
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="dropzone.js">
    </script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "dropzone.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "index.css">
<title> Share Your Images </title>
</head>

    <body>
<?php
        if (isset($_GET['url']) && $_GET['url'] === 'new') {   
echo "<style> .container {display:none;} </style>"; //hides the image selection form
echo "<link rel = 'stylesheet' href = 'imageGrid.css'>";
    $fileHandler->select_newest_posts();
}
elseif (isset($_GET['url'])) {        
   header("Location:/imagesharing/Images/" . $_GET['url']);
}
  ?>

        <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
   var spacingHeight = $("nav").outerHeight(true);
    $("img.bg").css("top", spacingHeight + "px");   

    $(".container").css("margin-top", spacingHeight + "px");      

    var bgArray = [];
    var currentIndex = 1;
    var timeOfFade = 1000;
     setInterval(function() {
    $("img.bg").attr("src", bgArray[currentIndex]);

         $("img.bg").css("opacity", .6);
   $("img.bg").fadeTo(timeOfFade, 0.9)
    currentIndex++;
    if (currentIndex == 3) {
    currentIndex = 0;
    }
    }, 6000);

    var heightOfDottedContainer =   $(".drop").outerHeight();

    setInterval(function() {
 heightOfDottedContainer =   $(".drop").outerHeight(); 
    heightOfDottedContainer /= 2; 
    heightOfDottedContainer += "px"; 
    $("span.dropText").css("bottom", heightOfDottedContainer);
    }, 350);

    setInterval(function() {

  var file = $("form input[type = file]").val();
        if (file != "") {
$("#fileText").text("Your file: " + file);
        }
    }, 200);

    $("[title = 'Browse']").mouseenter(function() {
       $(".hoverMenu").show(500);
    });

      $(".hoverMenu").mouseleave(function() {
       $(".hoverMenu").hide(500);
    });

    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var mydz = new Dropzone("#myzone");
});            

        </script>

<span class = "header">     
    <span class = "headerText"> Playpics 
        </span>      
<nav>       
<ul>     

  <li> <a href = "/imagesharing/index.php" title = "Home">  Home </a> </li>
  <li> <a href = "#" title = "Browse">  Browse </a> </li>
  <li> <a href = "#" title = "Help">  Help  </a> </li>

</ul>

    <div class = "hoverMenu"> 
    <div> <a href = "new">   New </a> </div>
    <div> <a href = "new">  Witcher 3 </a></div>
    <div> <a href = "new">  Skyrim </a> </div>
    <div> <!-- div for the form -->
    <form method = "GET" action = ""> 
    <input type = "text" name = "searchForTags" placeholder="Search by Tags">
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Search">
    </form>  
    </div>
    </div>    
</nav>   

</span>

<img class = "bg" src = "">

<div class = "container">      
    <div class = "drop">            
          <?php
    // user for testing this method $fileHandler->get_image_from_tags("witcher3");
    if (isset($fileHandler) && isset($feedback)) {
        echo $fileHandler->feedbackMessage($feedback);
    }

    ?>
       <span class = "dropText">  Drag Your Images Here (only .jpg, .jpeg, and .png)
        <br>
        <span id = "fileText"> </span>
        </span>

        </div> 

        <form action = "index.php" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <!-- form action must be set to index.php or dragging files will not work -->
    <input type = "file" id="files" name="file" multiple>
    <input type = "text" name = "tags" placeholder= "Enter any applicable tags (optional)">
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit">       
    </form>

    <form action = "index.php" class = "dropzone" id = "myzone">
        <?php if (isset($f)) {
    echo $f; 
}
    ?>
    <input type = "file" name = "files[]">
    </form>    
</div>          

</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest that you create a minimal, verifiable example from your code. As it is right now, it is quite impossible to reproduce the problem you’re having. Also, please try improving your problem statement. Do you get error messages? What results do you expect, and what happens instead?

Comment: can you update your question and provide full source of your code? i can't see your BODY tag..